# Case insensitive replace

Tags: python, string, case-insensitive

What's the easiest way to do a case-insensitive string replacement in Python?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

The `string` type doesn't support this. You're probably best off using [the regular expression sub method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with the [re.IGNORECASE](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) option.

```
>>> import re
>>> insensitive_hippo = re.compile(re.escape('hippo'), re.IGNORECASE)
>>> insensitive_hippo.sub('giraffe', 'I want a hIPpo for my birthday')
'I want a giraffe for my birthday'
```

Comment: If you're only doing a single replace, or want to save lines of code, it's more efficient to use a single substitution with re.sub and the (?i) flag: re.sub('(?i)' + re.escape('hippo'), 'giraffe', 'I want a hIPpo for my birthday')

Comment: Why **re.escape** for a string of letters only?  Thanks.

Comment: @Elena, it's not needed for `'hippo'`, but would be useful if the to-replace value was passed into a function, so it's really more of a good example than anything else.

Comment: Besides having to `re.escape` your needle, there's another trap here which this answer fails to avoid, noted in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15831118/1709587: since `re.sub` processes escape sequences, as noted in https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub, you need to either escape all backslashes in your replacement string or use a lambda.

Comment: This doesn't work for replacing `r'A\BC'` with `r'D\EF'` in `r'xxxA\BCxxxA\BCxxx')` - The correct answer is blow, the one from johv

Answer (score 111):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("hello", re.IGNORECASE)
pattern.sub("bye", "hello HeLLo HELLO")
# 'bye bye bye'
```

Comment: Or one-liner: 
`re.sub('hello', 'bye', 'hello HeLLo HELLO', flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: Note that `re.sub` only supports this flag since Python 2.7.

Comment: some times it return random strings

Answer (score 62):

In a single line:

```
import re
re.sub("(?i)hello","bye", "hello HeLLo HELLO") #'bye bye bye'
re.sub("(?i)he\.llo","bye", "he.llo He.LLo HE.LLO") #'bye bye bye'
```

Or, use the optional "flags" argument:

```
import re
re.sub("hello", "bye", "hello HeLLo HELLO", flags=re.I) #'bye bye bye'
re.sub("he\.llo", "bye", "he.llo He.LLo HE.LLO", flags=re.I) #'bye bye bye'
```

Answer (score 23):

Continuing on bFloch's answer, this function will change not one, but all occurrences of old with new - in a case insensitive fashion.

```
def ireplace(old, new, text):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(text):
        index_l = text.lower().find(old.lower(), idx)
        if index_l == -1:
            return text
        text = text[:index_l] + new + text[index_l + len(old):]
        idx = index_l + len(new) 
    return text
```

Comment: Very well done. Much better than regex; it handles all kinds of characters, whereas the regex is very fussy about anything non-alphanumeric. Preferred answer IMHO.

Comment: All you have to do is escape the regex: the accepted answer is much shorter and easier to read than this.

Comment: Escape only works for matching, backslashes in the destination can mess things up still.

Comment: Possibly the fastest method for a case-insensitive replace, tested against both using an arrayed string and using regex.

Answer (score 10):

Like Blair Conrad says string.replace doesn't support this.

Use the regex `re.sub`, but remember to escape the replacement string first. Note that there's no flags-option in 2.6 for `re.sub`, so you'll have to use the embedded modifier `'(?i)'` (or a RE-object, see Blair Conrad's answer). Also, another pitfall is that sub will process backslash escapes in the replacement text, if a string is given. To avoid this one can instead pass in a lambda.

Here's a function:

```
import re
def ireplace(old, repl, text):
    return re.sub('(?i)'+re.escape(old), lambda m: repl, text)

>>> ireplace('hippo?', 'giraffe!?', 'You want a hiPPO?')
'You want a giraffe!?'
>>> ireplace(r'[binfolder]', r'C:\Temp\bin', r'[BinFolder]\test.exe')
'C:\\Temp\\bin\\test.exe'
```

Answer (score 7):

This function uses both the `str.replace()` and `re.findall()` functions.
It will replace all occurences of `pattern` in `string` with `repl` in a case-insensitive way.

```
def replace_all(pattern, repl, string) -> str:
   occurences = re.findall(pattern, string, re.IGNORECASE)
   for occurence in occurences:
       string = string.replace(occurence, repl)
   return string
```

Answer (score 7):

An interesting observation about syntax details and options:

```
# Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import re
>>> old = "TREEROOT treeroot TREerOot"

>>> re.sub(r'(?i)treeroot', 'grassroot', old)
'grassroot grassroot grassroot'

>>> re.sub(r'treeroot', 'grassroot', old)
'TREEROOT grassroot TREerOot'

>>> re.sub(r'treeroot', 'grassroot', old, flags=re.I)
'grassroot grassroot grassroot'

>>> re.sub(r'treeroot', 'grassroot', old, re.I)
'TREEROOT grassroot TREerOot'
```

Using the `(?i)` prefix in the match expression or adding `flags=re.I` as a fourth argument will result in a case-insensitive match - however using just `re.I` as the fourth argument does not result in case-insensitive match.

For comparison:

```
>>> re.findall(r'treeroot', old, re.I)
['TREEROOT', 'treeroot', 'TREerOot']

>>> re.findall(r'treeroot', old)
['treeroot']
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.

Comment: From the [re.sub docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) it 5 parameters: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` which is why `flags=re.I` works but trying to pass it as a positional parameter fails, it's in the wrong position.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't require RegularExp

```
def ireplace(old, new, text):
    """ 
    Replace case insensitive
    Raises ValueError if string not found
    """
    index_l = text.lower().index(old.lower())
    return text[:index_l] + new + text[index_l + len(old):]
```

Comment: Good one, however this does not change all occurrences of old with new, but only the first occurrence.

Comment: It's less readable than the regex version. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: It would be interesting to do a performance comparison between this and the upvoted versions, it might be faster, which matters for some applications. Or it might be slower because it does more work in interpreted Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
i='I want a hIPpo for my birthday'
key='hippo'
swp='giraffe'

o=(i.lower().split(key))
c=0
p=0
for w in o:
    o[c]=i[p:p+len(w)]
    p=p+len(key+w)
    c+=1
print(swp.join(o))
```

Comment: For learning: generally when you do a search and replace on a string, it's better to not have to turn it into an array first. That's why the first answer is probably the best. While it's using an external module, it's treating the string as one whole string. It's also a bit clearer what's happening in the process.

Comment: For learning: its very difficult for a developer with no context to read this code and decipher what its doing :)

Comment: Any code that has counter++ is bad in general.

Answer (score 1):

I was having \t being converted to the [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (scroll a bit down), so I noted that [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) converts backslashed escaped characters to escape sequences.

To prevent that I wrote the following:

Replace case insensitive.

```
import re
    def ireplace(findtxt, replacetxt, data):
        return replacetxt.join(  re.compile(findtxt, flags=re.I).split(data)  )
```

Also, if you want it to replace with the escape characters, like the other answers here that are getting the special meaning bashslash characters converted to escape sequences, just decode your find and, or replace string.  In Python 3, might have to do something like .decode("unicode_escape") # python3

```
findtxt = findtxt.decode('string_escape') # python2
replacetxt = replacetxt.decode('string_escape') # python2
data = ireplace(findtxt, replacetxt, data)
```

Tested in Python 2.7.8

Answer (score 1):

1 line simple solution without imports :-)

```
words = 'GREETINGS from EGYPT. GreeTings from Cairo'
replace_what, replace_with,  = 'Greetings', 'Hello'

result = ' '.join([replace_with if word.lower() == replace_what.lower() else word for word in words.split(' ')])
print (result)
```

The result is:

```
Hello from EGYPT. Hello from Cairo
```