# How to replace a non-static substring case-insensitively

Tags: python, string, case-insensitive

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919056/python-case-insensitive-replace) except that the substring to be replaced is only known at the runtime.

I want to write the definition of `ireplace`, that behaves like this:

```
>>> ireplace(r'c:\Python26\lib\site.py', r'C:\python26', r'image\python26')
r'image\python26\lib\site.py'
>>>
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you don't want the returned string to start with c:\? If so, that's a little more than a replacement.

Comment: @Jon-Eric: That was my mistake, I fixed the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think this is the simplest way

```
r'c:\Python26\lib\site.py'.lower().replace('python26', r'image\python26')
```

For case insensitive, regexp is the simplest way

```
>>> def ireplace(s, a, b):
...     return re.sub("(?i)"+re.escape(a),b,s)
...
>>> print ireplace(r'c:\Python26\lib\site.py', 'C:\python26', r'image\python26')
image\python26\lib\site.py
```

Comment: Hmm, the implicit assumption is that I want to preserve the case for the input string. Your solution will not preserve case.

Comment: @Sridhar, I added a case insensitive version using regex. You should not be escaping `b` as you are not using it as a regex, just `a`

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it is simpler than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ireplace(s, a, b):
    """Replace `a` with `b` in s without caring about case"""
    re_a = re.compile(re.escape(a), re.IGNORECASE)
    return re_a.sub(lambda m: b, s)
```

Note: The `lambda m: b` hack is necessary, as `re.escape(b)` seems to mangle the string if it it has hyphens.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.