# Case-insensitive string replacement in python

Tags: python, regex

I am able to replace a word in a string content using the following solution in a case insensitive method

```
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/552726/ 
import re

class str_cir(str):
        ''' A string with a built-in case-insensitive replacement method '''

        def ireplace(self,old,new,count=0):
        ''' Behaves like S.replace(), but does so in a case-insensitive
        fashion. '''
            pattern = re.compile(re.escape(old),re.I)
            return re.sub(pattern,new,self,count)
```

My problem is i need to replace exactly the word i provide like

```
para = "Train toy tram dog cat cow plane TOY  Joy   JoyTOY"
```

i need to replace the word "toy" with "ham" and i get

```
'Train HAM tram dog cat cow plane HAM  Joy   JoyHAM'
```

What i need is

```
'Train HAM tram dog cat cow plane HAM  Joy   JoyTOY'
```

Comment: Just to note - the indentation isn't correct - and I think the actual code is `para = str_cri("...")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919056/case-insensitive-replace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\b` to the start and end of the keyword:

```
pattern = re.compile("\\b" + re.escape(old) + "\\b",re.I)
```

`\b` means word boundary, and it matches the empty string at the start and end of a word (defined by sequence of alphanumeric or underscore character). ([Reference](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html))

As @Tim Pietzcker pointed out, it won't work as you might think if there are non-word (not alphanumeric and not underscore) characters in the keyword.

Comment: This. (Let's just hope that his search "words" never start or end with a non-alphanumeric character)

Comment: Hi Guys this method works for me as the terms i search are always alphanumeric characters. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put `\b` at the beginning and ending of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the word you're using in the regular expression with word boundaries (`\b`).

Comment: putting `\b` at both ends would be same as putting `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end?

Comment: @theharshest Nope, `\b` are word boundaries while `^` and `$` position at the start and end of string.

Comment: but if I put `^` and `$` at start and end, then also it will match the exact re enclosed, solve the same purpose as `\b` does. Right?