# Python Case Insensitive Replace All of multiple strings

Tags: python, regex, case-insensitive

I want to replace all occurrences of a set of strings in a text line.  I came up with this approach, but I am sure there is a better way of doing this:

```
myDict = {}
test = re.compile(re.escape('pig'), re.IGNORECASE)
myDict['car'] = test
test = re.compile(re.escape('horse'), re.IGNORECASE)
myDict['airplane'] = test
test = re.compile(re.escape('cow'), re.IGNORECASE)
myDict['bus'] = test

mystring = 'I have this Pig and that pig with a hOrse and coW'

for key in myDict:      
    regex_obj = myDict[key]
    mystring = regex_obj.sub(key, mystring)

print mystring
```

I have this car and that car with a airplane and bus

Based on @Paul Rooney's answer below, ideally I would do this:

```
def init_regex():
    rd = {'pig': 'car', 'horse':'airplane', 'cow':'bus'}
    myDict = {}
    for key,value in rd.iteritems():
        pattern = re.compile(re.escape(key), re.IGNORECASE)
        myDict[value] = pattern

    return myDict

def strrep(mystring, patternDict):
    for key in patternDict:
        regex_obj = patternDict[key]
        mystring = regex_obj.sub(key, mystring)

    return mystring
```

Comment: I am not sure there is anything significantly better than this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919056/python-case-insensitive-replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import itertools
import re

mystring = 'I have this Pig and that pig with a hOrse and coW'

rd = {'pig': 'car', 'horse':'airplane', 'cow':'bus'}

cachedict = {}

def strrep(orig, repdict):
    for k,v in repdict.iteritems():
        if k in cachedict:
            pattern = cachedict[k]
        else:
            pattern = re.compile(k, re.IGNORECASE)
            cachedict[k] = pattern
        orig = pattern.sub(v, orig)
    return orig

print strrep(mystring, rd)
```

This answer was initially written for python2, but for python 3 you would use `repdict.items`  instead of `repdict.iteritems`.

Comment: Is it possible to cache the compile to save on computation as my strrep would be called multiple times?

Comment: Based on your answer I improved the solution to cache the compiled portion of the code into an array so I don't have to do this everytime and then just call the patter with .sub

Comment: Yes that works. I was looking at a solution to cache the compiled regex's into a dict.

Comment: The `dict` caching solution seems to actually be a bit slower than without the caching.

Comment: The reason your approach to a dictionary degrades performance is probably because you specify a default if the key is not found.  I would venture to guess that python performs the compile before calling the get which causes the additional compute unnecessarily every time.

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Yep it’s a python 2 only function, use ‘items’ instead of ‘iteritems’. As the question is not tagged python 2 I will update.