# What's the easiest way to do a case-insensitive string replacement in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Is there a way to get a case insensitive regex replace to work on a Pandas dataframe? I would prefer to keep the work vectorised instead of having to resort to creating a loop at the string level to which re.sub is [apparently limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/919067/5088194).)

(When I try to use re.sub with the dataframe the compiler complains that it needs strings.)

```
fables['animal_names'] = re.sub(r"(^|\s+|,)hippo(,|\s+|$)"," Hippopotamus ", fables['animal_names'])
```

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Passing `case=True`?

Comment: Does the regular string `.str` accessor [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) not work?  It has a `case` parameter that can be set to `False`...

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html how about this method (works on Series)

Comment: or this one : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html 
Using `regex=True`

Comment: So then str.replace does take ignorecase arguments! Adding all of the above works.