# Python defining function under condition

Tags: python

Is this code correct in python?

```
def foo(flag):
    if flag:
        def bar():
           # Somthing
    else:
        def bar():
           # Somthing else
    bar()

foo(True)
foo(False)
```

if not what is a recommended way to set behavior of some function (bar) under? condition?

OK The real code is following

```
# Building replaceFunc based of ignore_case and use_regexp flags
if not ignore_case:
   if not use_regexp:
      def replaceFunc(string, search, replace):
          return string.replace(search, replace)
   else:
      def replaceFunc(string, search, replace):
          pattern = re.compile(search)
          return pattern.sub(replace, string)
else:
   if not use_regexp:
       # There is no standard puthon function for replacing string by ignoring case
       def replaceFunc(string, search, replace):
          # implementation from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919056/case-insensitive-replace
           return string
   else:
        def replaceFunc(string, search, replace):
            pattern = re.compile(search, re.IGNORECASE)
            return pattern.sub(replace, string
```

Comment: Why don't you put the if inside bar? Why do you need bar at all?

Comment: Why don't you place your  if, else inside `bar`

Comment: The real case is too complicated. I have tried to put simplified code. In real example bar is called inside for cycle. It also need to be passed to other function

Comment: Such a reductive example does not allow anyone to give you a useful answer. Please [edit] to provide context.

Comment: This is perfectly correct. Whether it is the best solution depends on many things, including personal preference. Anyway, it does seem like there could be better solutions...

Comment: OK Now I put complete solution

Comment: Why not use polymorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one reasonable way to achieve what you want:

```
def bar1():
    return 'b1'

def bar2():
    return 'b2'

def foo(flag):
    bar = bar2 if flag else bar1
    return bar()

print(foo(False))
print(foo(True))
```

One benefit of defining the functions `bar1()` and `bar2()` outside of `foo()` is that they can be unit tested.

Comment: OK Thanks. This will work. Is the way to avoid from unneccary indiced names. In my case they will be bar1 bar2 bar3 bar4. Doesn't looks nice.

Comment: @ArmanHunanyan Sure, you can name the functions any way you like. Give them meaningful names — not `bar1`, `bar2`, etc.