# How can I write a program in python to replace character in string with other character irrespective of case-letter

Tags: python

I want this program ignore case letter 
E.g. for string 'Apple' either 'A' or 'a' can replace the 'A' in Apple with any other character.

```
store = []

def main(text=input("Enter String: ")):

  replace = input("Enter the replace char: ")
  replace_with = input("Enter the replace with char: ")

  for i in text:
    store.append(i)


main()
print(store)  # printing the result here

f_result = ''.join(store)  # Joining back to original state 
print(f_result)
```

Comment: What about `text.replace(replace.upper(), replace_with).replace(replace.lower(), replace_with)` ?

Comment: ^^^ this is why we don't use python built-ins as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `re` standard library which has the `sub` method and an option to ignore case. It is also convenient to use. This works for your example:

```
import re

def main(text=input("Enter String: ")):

    replace = input("Enter the replace char: ")
    replace_with = input("Enter the replace with char: ")

    return re.sub(replace, replace_with, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

main()

>>Enter String: Apple
>>Enter the replace char: a
>>Enter the replace with char: B
>>'Bpple'
```

Comment: yeah! I am new here and also new to python language. I was trying hard myself to write my own algorithm without using built -in function.

Comment: No problem, just remember to keep it as simple and usable :) You can do `import this` if you would want to learn the zen of Python. BTW just in cased you missed out on [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ascii numbers. The difference between the code for an uppercase and it's respective lower case is 32

Comment: I tried  and also searched the internet for the solution using ascii number but didn't get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple posts on Stack Overflow about case-insensitive string replacements in python, but almost all of them involve using regular expressions. (For example see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919056/case-insensitive-replace).)

IMO, the simplest thing in this case would be to make 2 calls to `str.replace`. First replace the upper case version and then replace the lower case version.

Here is an example:

```
text = "Apple"
to_repl = "a"
repl_with = "B"
print(text.replace(to_repl.upper(), repl_with).replace(to_repl.lower(), repl_with))
#Bpple
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I was thinking that is there any other way without using built-in function. Like writing our own algorithm to solve a specific problem without taking any help of built-in function.  Still your answer appreciated! thanks:)

Comment: @ManishGupta seems like you want to avoid calling `str.replace` - you could do: `"".join([t if t not in [to_repl.lower(), to_repl.upper()] else repl_with for t in text])`