# Delete a string if matching with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, automation

I want to recognize if the words from a list are in an input string, and if so remove that word.

I have tried:

```
words = ["youtube","search youtube","play music"]
Inp = "search youtube Rockstar"

if words in Inp:
   Inp = Inp.replace(words,"")
```

And the wanted output is:

```
Inp = "Rockstar"
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `artificial-intelligence`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit complected to remove space separated strings from a string. You have to do some hacks to achive this.

**Steps:**

1. Firstly you have to generate an unique list of words that you want to remove
2. Remove filtered words from the string
3. Create a new list of words from previously generated string
4. Finally join the list to remove unnecessary spaces

**Code:**

```
import re


def remove_matching_string(my_string, words):
    # generate an unique list of words that we want to remove
    removal_list = list(set(sum([word.split() for word in words], [])))

    # remove strings from removal list
    for word in removal_list:
        insensitive_str = re.compile(re.escape(word), re.IGNORECASE)
        my_string = insensitive_str.sub('', my_string)

    # split string after apply removal list
    my_string = my_string.split()

    # concat string to remove unnecessary space between words
    final_string = ' '.join(s for s in my_string if s)

    # return the final string
    return final_string


words = ["youtube","search youtube","play music"]
Inp = "Search youtube Rockstar Play Music On Youtube   PlAy MusIc Now"

final_string = remove_matching_string(Inp, words)
print(final_string)
```

**Output:**

```
Rockstar On Now
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the `words` list and replace each word.

```
for word in words:
    Inp = Inp.replace(word, '')
```

If there's overlap between the elements of `words`, such as `youtube` and `search youtube`, you need to put the longer one first. Otherwise, when `youtube` is removed, it won't find `search youtube` to replace it. So make it:

```
words = ["search youtube","youtube","play music"]
```

If you can't change `words` like this, you can sort them when looping:

```
for word in sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True):
```

Comment: That won't work with the example in the question. It will replace "youtube", not "search youtube".

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, I've updated the answer to show how to fix the `words` list.

Comment: Your solution will fail for `case sensitive` strings. :)

Comment: @Sabil True, but there's no indication that case-insensitiviity is required. If that's needed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919056/case-insensitive-replace

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop as so:

```py
words = ["youtube","search youtube","play music"]
Inp = "search youtube Rockstar"

for word in words:
  if word in Inp:
    Inp = inp.replace(word, '')
  else:
    pass

print(Inp)
```